# Python ImportError inside project files

Tags: python, flask, python-import

I got stuck on import error when running `python manage.py db migrate` for my Flask app. I tried a lot of combinations with import statements in traceback files (general, local).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "src/manage.py", line 7, in <module>
         from api import app, db
     File "/api/src/api.py", line 6, in <module>
         import auth.views
     File "/api/src/auth/views.py", line 3, in <module>
         import models
     File "/api/src/models.py", line 2, in <module>
         from api import app
ImportError: cannot import name 'app'
```

Any idea?

Comment: circular import?

Comment: It will be helpful if you share project structure and the content of `api.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

app_settings = os.getenv(
    'APP_SETTINGS',
    'config.DevelopmentConfig'
)
app.config.from_object(app_settings)

bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# Try by keeping the import here?
import auth.views
app.register_blueprint(auth.views.auth_blueprint)
```

Most probable reason for this issue would be that you are referring **app** Flask object in your auth.views and models even before you create the **app** object....

ImportError: cannot import name 'app'

so if you import the auth.views after your app creation, then the reference would work....

Comment: Thank you. Looks like it was main mistake.